# Express-validation not producing the correct errors

Tags: node.js, express-validator

So, this worked before, and all the sudden decided to stop working, and I have no idea why.

EDIT: Updated the code to show what I currently got now

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

  // let query
  let query;

  // Start email checks
  req.check('email', 'Email is not valid.')
  .isEmail()
  .custom(async value => {
    query = {email: value};
    User.findOne(query).then(user => {
      if (user) return false;
    });
  }).withMessage('Email is in use.');

  // Start username checks
  req.check('username', 'Username is required.')
  .notEmpty()
  .isLength({ min: 5, max: 15}).withMessage('Username requires 5-15 alphanumberic characters.')
  .isAlphanumeric().withMessage('Username must be alphanumeric only.')
  .custom(async value => {
    query = {username: value}
    User.findOne(query).then(user => {
      if (user) return false;
    });
  }).withMessage('Username is in use.');

  // Start password checks
  req.check('password', 'Password is required.')
  .notEmpty()
  .isLength({min: 5}).withMessage('Password must be atleast 5 characters long.');
  req.check('confirmPassword', 'Confirm Password is required.')
  .notEmpty()
  .custom(value => value === req.body.password).withMessage('Password must match');


  const errors = await req.getValidationResult();
  //console.log(errors);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      res.render('index', {
      errors: errors.mapped()
    });
  } else {
    let newUser = new User({
      email: req.body.email,
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);     
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render('index', {
          success: 'Registration Successful'
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

So its pretty clear its something with my custom checks, and I do not know why.

EDIT:
It seems there is confusion. The checks are working correctly, what I'm having issues with is it populating the errors when I want it to. If i try to register with the same email, it will pull up the user and will go through my if statements. If I use Promise.reject() it doesn't work. If I use false, it doesn't work. Again, the checks itself work, the error handling seems like it isn't.

EDIT TWO:
So I have tried this method (all the other code is still the same)

```
// Start email checks
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid.')
.isEmail()
.custom(value => {
  query = {email: value}
  User.findOne(query).then(user => {
    if (user) console.log('Email Exists'); return false;
  });
}).withMessage('Email in use.');

// Start username checks
req.check('username', 'Username is required.')
.notEmpty()
.isLength({ min: 5, max: 15}).withMessage('Username requires 5-15 alphanumberic characters.')
.isAlphanumeric().withMessage('Username must be alphanumeric only.')
.custom(value => {
  query = {username: value}
  User.findOne(query).then(user => {
    if (user) console.log('Username Exists'); return false;
  });
}).withMessage('Username in use.');
```

Comment: `req.check('usrname)....`  just `check( 'username)....`

Comment: That only works before the function starts. Inside the function you need a `req.` before it.

Comment: In the docs they're using `app.post('/register',[validations],(req,res)=>{ })`

Comment: You can do it both ways. I don't think you read through my post. It will not return the errors in my async custom validations, but the others it will. I know this works because I've done it before. I do not know why its not working now: The problem isnt with the checking, its the returning of the errors. the checks work properly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Since node.js is non render blocking,the db query may not complete before it proceeds to next step. You could use the format I have posted below or try the async library in which case `await` keyword should be placed before `User.findOne`

```
 User.findOne(query).then(user=>{
     if(user) return false
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Neither of those worked, updated OP to reflect what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer, which incidentally makes it a little easier to read as well. I ended up making my own custom validators:

```
  customValidators: {
    emailExists: (email) => {
      let query = {email: email};
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne(query, (err, results) => {
          if (results === null) {
            resolve(err);
          }
          reject(results);
        });
      });
    },
    userNameExists: (username) => {
      let query = {username: username};
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        User.findOne(query, (err, results) => {
          if (results === null) {
            resolve(err);
          }
          reject(results);
        });
      });
    }
  },
```

Then:

```
  req.check('email', 'This email is in use.').emailExists();
  req.check('username', 'Username is in use.').userNameExists();
  req.asyncValidationErrors().then(() => {
    console.log('No errors');
    let newUser = new User({
      email: req.body.email,
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    let hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);     
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render('index', {
          success: 'Registration Successful'
        });
      }
    });
  }).catch(errors => {
    res.render('index', {
      errors: errors
    });
  });
```